Configure colour of bookmarks in Delphi IDE
The Delphi IDE has a fantastic feature of numbered bookmarks. Use Ctrl + Shift + (1-9) to set/unset a bookmark, and Ctrl + (1-9) to jump to the bookmark. Both Visual Studio Code and Studio Studio have extensions to implement this feature (Numbered Bookmarks and VSBookmarks respectively).
My question is whether the colour or size of the bookmark is configurable (in either Delphi 7 or Delphi 12). In the image, Delphi 7 is on the left and Delphi 12 is on the right.


Do you know the Parnassus Bookmarks plugin already (available on GetIt with active Subscription only)?

@DelphiCoder: I was not aware of that, will check it out. The in-built bookmark support is pretty much perfect, though, so would prefer to make these bookmarks easier to read if possible.

You'll see it is not as perfect as you think ;-)
